# How to properly Load balance between two Spark Controllers

Tags: vora

We are attempting to load balance between two Spark Controllers that connect to Vora...

We are capable of connecting and the query gets sent to the controller.
the problem occurs when the result is supposed to be passed back to hana the process hangs and will never finish.

[image]

The last lines in logs state :

```
17/02/14 14:24:12 INFO CommandRouter$$anon$1: Created broadcast 7 from executeSelectTask at CommandRouter.scala:650
17/02/14 14:24:12 INFO CommandRouter$$anon$1: Starting job: executeSelectTask at CommandRouter.scala:650
17/02/14 14:24:12 INFO CommandRouter$$anon$1: Created broadcast 8 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1008
17/02/14 14:24:14 INFO CommandRouter$$anon$1: Created broadcast 9 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1008
```

Is there something specific to be configured for allowing to load balance between the two controllers?

Answer (score 0):

The reason the process hangs forever is because the nodes where the Spark executor jobs are running do not know the hostname of the HANA host and therefore are never able to return the resultset. This must be added to the node's /etc/hosts file.